# Библиотеки MediaPipe не импортируются в AndroidStudio с помощью Bazel

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь импортировать библиотеки MediaPipe в AndroidStudio с помощью Bazel, используя инструкцию  https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/docs/install.md#using-mediapipe-with-bazel .

На 8 шаге все перестало получаться. Выводит много таких предупреждений,а затем ошибку сборки

```
WARNING: 
/home/masha/mediapipe/mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/objectdetectiongpu_aar/BUILD:3:1: in srcs attribute of android_library rule //mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/objectdetectiongpu_aar:mp_hand_tracking_aar_android_lib: please do not import '//mediapipe/java/com/google/mediapipe/components:AudioDataConsumer.java' directly. You should either move the file to this package or depend on an appropriate rule there. Since this rule was created by the macro 'mediapipe_aar', the error might have been caused by the macro implementation in /home/masha/mediapipe/mediapipe/examples/android/src/java/com/google/mediapipe/apps/objectdetectiongpu_aar/BUILD:3:1
```

Не понимаю как это исправить.

Так же выводит предупреждение

```
WARNING: API level 29 specified by android_ndk_repository 'androidndk' is not available. Using latest known API level 28
```

Не могу найти где изменить уровень API, если проблема вообще в этом.
Посмотрите, пожалуйста, очень нужна помощь, одна не справляюсь((

Answer (score 0):

1. Попробуйте собрать с помощью Bazel, не в студии, для начала Hello World.
2. Установки правильные, NDK и SDK. Обычно ошибки сыпятся, если не те версии.
3. В сборке aar мне помогла [эта ссылка](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/blob/master/mediapipe/docs/android_archive_library.md)
4. Также желательно понимать, что за rule такие и в чем [ошибка](https://habr.com/ru/post/502440/)

---

PS 
На предупреждение можно не обращать внимание.
Для более конкретного ответа необходимо указать: какая ОС используется, а также версии Bazel, Python3 и компиляторов gcc и g++.